# How to identify which USB devices are mapped to what network interface names?

Tags: usb, network-adapter, udev, network-interface, usb-network-adapter

When I plug in an USB network, it gets assigned a network name, like `wlan1` by *udev*. Is there a way how to determine the mapping, without going through *udev* files, like `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `lshw` (install as needed). The command `lshw -C Network` answers your question.

For example the usb network device connected at usb bus 2:1.5 (check `lsusb -t` for more info on your usb tree) has logical name wlan0:

```
root@kali:~# lshw -C Network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1.5
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:60:64:37:4a:30
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.14-kali1-amd64 firmware=0.29 ip=10.0.0.4 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```